# Does a Reishi rich environment prevent flying?

Tags: bleach

In Bleach, there are times when we see Soul Reapers (and Visoreds) stand in the air. Examples are like when Ikkaku releases his Bankai during Grimmjow's initial attack, when Shinji first reveals himself as a Visored to Ichigo, or way back in Season 1 when Ichigo was fighting Sora. This was also mentioned by Kisuke when he was training Ichigo where in Lesson 2 - Shattered Shaft he says that Ichigo can get out if he flew out and the purpose of Lesson 2 was to restore Ichigo as a Soul Reaper.

However when we see Soul Reapers fight in the Soul Society or in Hueco Mundo we don't see this. We don't see Soul Reapers standing in mid air to get a height advantage on Ichigo and his friends when they went to rescue Rukia and so far (up to Episode 157) I have not seen Ichigo, Rukia or Renji fly.

Both the Soul Society and Hueco Mundo, as stated by Uryuu, are rich in Reishi. So I am wondering, does a Reishi rich environment prevent flying?

Comment: while they might not always do this, i do recall the fight between Ichigo and Grimmjow. Grimmjow did stand on the air to deliver his final move, and this did create a height advantage in this case. Ichigo, after stabbing him, stood in the air and watched him fall. I might have spoiled it for you, as i can't recall the episode number now.

Comment: @NicholasAysen don't worry about the spoilers, i ask knowing full well that an answer might contain spoilers.

Comment: Don't they use reshi as footholds to stand on air? In the latter episodes, the last animated arc, Ikkaku is fighting and notes that he was just standing, despite being in the air. Could simply be that the cost to stand in air in high reshi environments is too costly to be efficient, at least until you get very powerful, which i do believe is shown in the manga only right now. Id have to check the sources, but i don't have such time right now

Comment: I believe that the reason they float outside of Soul Society or Hueco Mundo is because they don't want to mess with the people who are not already part of their 'world.' In the Soul Society, everyone already knows about shinigami and the like, but in the mortal world most people don't even know that shinigami exist. So they fight in the air so the humans don't get caught in the cross-fire.